# How to make Chrome respond to the Service Changed Characteristic?

Tags: google-chrome, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have a small device implementing a Bluetooth server and a JS page which I open on Chrome that connects and manipulate some of the device characteristics.
Since I'm still playing with the server code, I'm constantly changing/adding services and characteristics and noticed that Chrome still shows my the old ones (actually, more like an unclear mix of old and new ones). Other devices like my phone show the new characteristics.

How can I order Chrome to rediscover services and delete its cache? I've tried to just define the Service Change Characteristic and it didn't help, then tried notify the client upon connection with the values 0x0000 and 0xFFFF (assuming that would invalidate the whole range of handles) but nothing happened..

Also - what does Chrome take as the device name? (in case there are multiple "names", I refer to what's displayed in the scan window). I've tried to set the name in the "aioble.advertise()" function, and also set it in the device name characteristic (0x2A00 under the generic access service) and both didn't change the value. It's still showed as "ESP32" which I believe is some kind of default..

I was hinted that the bluetooth spec is implemented differently between Chrome/Android/iPhone/etc.. So I was hoping to get an answer of how does Chrome implement the Service Changed feature? What should I do as the server to order the client to refetch services data?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked at the Web Bluetooth [Draft Community Report](https://webbluetoothcg.github.io/web-bluetooth/), last updated on 9 June 2022. Section [6.6.5. Responding to Service Changes](https://webbluetoothcg.github.io/web-bluetooth/#service-change-events) describes how Web Bluetooth might be supposed to handle a service changed event.

But according to the [Implementation Status](https://github.com/WebBluetoothCG/web-bluetooth/blob/main/implementation-status.md), the Service Changed Event is not implemented on any of the platforms as of now.

You could open an [issue](https://github.com/WebBluetoothCG/web-bluetooth/issues) on their Github page to get more information.